# Object gets disposed too early?

Tags: asp.net, owin, katana

This puzzles me. I have this OWIN/Katana middleware:

```
 class M1 : OwinMiddleware
    {
        public M1(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next) { }
        public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200); ; // do something
                string reqUrl = context.Request.Uri.ToString(); //<- throws exception
            })
                .ContinueWith(t => this.Next.Invoke(context));

        }
    }
```

and then a Startup class:

```
   public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                return Task.Run(() =>
                {
                }).ContinueWith(t => next());
            });

            app.Use<M1>();
        }
    }
```

Running this throws an ObjectDisposedException in M1:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name:
>   'System.Net.HttpListenerRequest'.

Stack trace:

> at System.Net.HttpListenerRequest.CheckDisposed()    at
>   System.Net.HttpListenerRequest.GetKnownHeader(HttpRequestHeader
>   header)    at System.Net.HttpListenerRequest.get_UserHostName()    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.RequestProcessing.RequestHeadersDictionary.TryGetValue(String
>   key, String[]& value)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.HeaderDictionary.TryGetValue(String key, String[]&
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.GetHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2
>   headers, String key)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.GetHeader(IDictionary`2
>   headers, String key)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.GetHost(IOwinRequest
>   request)    at Microsoft.Owin.OwinRequest.get_Host()

If I remove that anonymous middleware before *app.Use();* then no exception is thrown.

Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do?

Comment: It looks like you are accessing `context` asynchronously, after some logic in Owin disposes of it. I know nothing of Owin, but this looks like very convoluted logic to me.

Comment: I've just started learning it, but it looks very much like Node/ExpressJS.

Answer (score 1):

You should use await instead of ContinueWith to avoid returning control to owin pipeline before middleware is executed. Something like this:

```
class M1 : OwinMiddleware
{
    public M1(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next) { }
    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200); ; // do something
            string reqUrl = context.Request.Uri.ToString(); //<- throws exception
        });

        await this.Next.Invoke(context);    
     }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await Task.Run(() => { });
                    await next();
            });

            app.Use<M1>();
        }
    }
}
```